# Create an app for tablet and phone using a ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I read that ConstraintLayout is a great tool for creating an app for multiple screen sizes, like tablet and phone.
But even tho' the layout itself scales (from what I have seen) between different screen sizes, what can I do about the text size of a TextView, for example?
How can I make it scale as well?
Also if you have any knowledge of a better way to write an app for phone and tablets as well feel free to tell me (I would prefer not to create different layouts for all types of screens).

Code Sample:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.merchantproxy.merchantproxy.activities.DashboardActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_dashboard">
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/dashboardScrollView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="157dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dashboardDataLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:id="@+id/salesCard"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="170dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.05"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
                        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
                        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
                        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp">


                        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/salesTextView"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="0dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                                android:text="Sales"
                                android:textSize="20sp"
                                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/salesStats"
                                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                                android:id="@+id/salesStats"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="100dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

                                <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                                    android:id="@+id/guideline"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:orientation="vertical"
                                    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.33" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/totalSales"
                                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                                    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                                    android:text="$0"
                                    android:textAlignment="center"
                                    android:textColor="@color/colorSuccess"
                                    android:textSize="35sp"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"
                                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                                    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
                                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:id="@+id/netSalesLayout"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                                    android:orientation="vertical"
                                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.538"
                                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/feesLayout"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.963"
                                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/netSales"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                        android:text="$0"
                                        android:textAlignment="center"
                                        android:textColor="@color/colorSuccess"
                                        android:textSize="35sp"
                                        android:textStyle="bold"
                                        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="24dp"
                                        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="208dp" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="Net Sales"
                                        android:textAlignment="center"
                                        android:textSize="20sp"
                                        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="24dp"
                                        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="208dp" />
                                </LinearLayout>
```

UI:
[image: UI]

**I mention that i have this issue only on phones that are oriented vertically...if I rotate the view to landscape everything scales ok**

Comment: Simply follow the *`common guidelines`*: use **dp** for the View sizes and **sp** for the font sizes.

Comment: I did that, but when I switch to phone the text itself is simply not displayed entirely ...parts of it are left out. Should I use a horizontal scroll?

Comment: There might be something wrong in your layout.

Comment: i will post a sample code in a moment

Comment: @ModularSynth I have posted a code sample

Comment: ... `android:layout_width="0dp"`?! Wait! is it inside another LinearLayout, which uses weights?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152522/discussion-between-alphonse-and-modularsynth).

Comment: @ModularSynth I have posted the entire front-end tree now

Comment: It's not the full layout. It ends abruptly after the innermost LinearLayout. What I can tell is that there's too much **layout nesting**, the ScrollView is **inside** the ContraintLayout (?!) and it has `android:layout_width="0dp"` **AND** `android:layout_height="0dp"` (!!).